# Watch innerHTML of a vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, markdown

I am currently using a npm package vue3-markdown-it to render markdown on some of my content. Now as soon as the component renders, I want to use its innerHTML and make some custom changes of my own before sending the content to my div
However, as soon as the content changes, vue3-markdown-it takes some time to render the markdown, which is fine but if I add a watcher to the change of the content, the innerhtml of markdown component returns empty. I want to watch the innerHTML of the component so I can run my change function when it finishes rendering. Any idea how to acheive it?

```
data(){
return{
content: 'My content',
}
}

// at change of content markdown component automatically renders the
// new content with formatting, but it returns old data until rendering
// is complete, so I want to wait for the rendering to complete but
// without adding a timeout

watch: {
content: {
handler: function(){
myDiv.innerHTML = markedComponent.innerHTML + 'my changes'
}
}

// desired result
'markedComponent.innerHTML my changes'

// result I'm getting
"my changes"
```

Comment: Delay the access of innerhtml with nextTick

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks, but how would I go about doing that if I wanted my function to run every time the content changes in data?

Comment: Same as above, nextTick should be inside handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using nextTick should solve your problem.

```
watch: {
  content: {
    handler(){
      Vue.nextTick(() => {
        myDiv.innerHTML = markedComponent.innerHTML + 'my changes'
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Composition API would look like this:

```
<script setup>
import { watch, nextTick } from 'vue'
watch(
  () => content, 
  () => nextTick(() => { myDiv.innerHTML = markedComponent.innerHTML + 'my changes' }
)
</script>
```